# Using Jackson to build custom JSON with or without Marshaling?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Am building a JSON String like this:

```
public String buildAutoCompleteQuery(int from, int pageSize, String criteria) {
    StringBuilder autoComplete = new StringBuilder();
    autoComplete.append("{").append("\"from\"").append(":").append(from).append(",").append("\"size\"").append(":").append(pageSize).append(",").append("\"query\"").append(":").append("{").append("\"match\"").append(":").append("{")
            .append("\"full_text\"").append(":").append("\"").append(criteria).append("\"").append("}").append("}}");
    return autoComplete.toString();
}
```

After putting in sample parameters, when you print it (with pretty printing) it looks like this:

```
{
    "from": 1,
    "size": 15,
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "full_text": "Hello"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an easier way to create this JSON object using Jackson (with or without marshalling / databinding)?

Answer (score 0):

One way you should try is that you can create a class for the object and then use Jackson to convert the object to string.

```
{
"from": 1,
"size": 15,
"query": {
    "match": {
        "full_text": "Hello"
    }
  }
}
```

Now create Classes for this like

```
public class AutoComplete{
   private Integer from;
   private Integer size;
   private Query query;
    // getters and setters
}

public class Query{
  private Match match;
}

public class Match{
  private String full_text;
}
```

Then use Jackson to convert the autocomplete object, you will get the required JSON string.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without marshaling? The reason I ask is because the match query is always different so I have to hard code it as a JSON string.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your requirement

Comment: This is really to use RestClient to hard code Elasticsearch Queries... Am not using the API it provides, am using low level RestClient so every match content is different. Some queries don't even have a match subsection at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Jackson's ObjectMapper for these purposes. You may want to create a set of objects, describing your ecosystem (as in previous comment).

(Direction object -> json) If you have an object and you want to get a JSON string use ObjectMapper#writeValueAsString(Object value)

(Direction json-> object)  If you have a json string of maybe a json file and want to get an object use ObjectMapper#readValue(String content, Class valueType) for example. 
Check nice examples [in here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

I personally find ObjectMapper very convenient, you can configure it to ignore null values or let's say private members of serialized class.